# Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity

I'm developing an Android app with Xamarin and I was able to understand how to create a button and go from the main layout1 to layout2 but when I try to go from layout2 to layout3 the button doesn't work and I've been trying to research and get nothing.

I tried putting this code in the MainActivity.cs and in the second Activity so it can go to layout3 but I noticed my code works from MainActivity.cs to go to layout3 but the code doesn't work from layout2 to go to layout3 - help please?

`Button BreakFast = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BTN_MAINMENU_BREAKFAST);
 BreakFast.Click += delegate {SetContentView(Resource.Layout.BreakfastMenu);};`

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: Are you creating a new Activity or trying to load a different layout? Review the Android training docs on starting a new activity: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I've already been to the docs that's why I'm here....

Comment: @Christian From the code snippet in your question you should review that first app training guide, you need to create a new Activity subclass and load your new layout in that activity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, because what you're doing is kind of freakish to me, but since you're setting a new layout you should bind the new id's to the button. I'm guessing you have a button on layout 2, which should take you to layout 3. You should bind the variable to a view's id.

Also... don't do that. Create another activity, so when it start `onCreate` will be called and that will bind your views.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I'm just trying to get from layout2 to layout3 but it doesn't work. I'm able to get from layout1 to layout2 - the code I'm showing is the code you need to do that but it doesn't work from the second layout2 to layout3

Comment: @Christian - sure. I think the proper way for you would be to have three activities and for each of these activities you should have a layout. Then, you don't call `setLayout` but instead you call startActivity. When activity start a method called `onCreate` is called, where you do the `findViewById`, and that's what you're missing when you just swap layouts. Try this : https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/

Comment: If you just simply pasted the `startActivity` it won't work. Do the following: 1. Abandon the project for a while. 2. Start a new project. 3. Create an Activity1 and create it's layout (layout1). 4. In this layout create a button and bind it to activity (findViewById). 5. Start another activity, with it's own layout, create a button there, and also bind the view to a button variable, set OnClick action (delegate) which will start Activity3. 6. Then create activity three similarly to the previous two. Every time you create activity, you need to create it's layout and bind the views to variables